# Redirect pages after removing filename extension from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've followed [this](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) tutorial as to how to remove the file extention from the URL. The problem is, I also need to redirect a few pages that had their names changed.

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```html
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^old\-page\-name$ /new-page-name
```

The problem is, that redirection does not work. It works when adding the trailing `.php` and in that case, it adds a port (7080) to the address, so it looks like `domain.com:7080/new-address.php`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To anyone wanting a full solution, read the comments of the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect the same name to php and html. You can use a test with:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

RewriteRule ^old\-page\-name$ /new-page-name
```

Place first the one you use the most (php or html)
You can also change all your signature in php (if the php is very used)

The redirection to port 7080 does not seem to be related to this htaccess

And `MultiViews` try to do the same. You can't use both.

Comment: Hmm those are all good points and you are right! But the page redirection is not working yet... It's like it's not matching but it's corrent (I think :) )

Comment: And if you try to redirect (and not just rewrite) use `[L,R=302]` (use 302 for test and after change for 301)

Comment: No dice... maybe my syntax is wrong...? This is what I currently have: `RewriteRule ^parceiros$ /parceiros2 [L,R=302]` the address is http://interfusaoti.com.br/parceiros (pardon the portuguese)

Comment: If the page still exists, you must place `RewriteRule ^parceiros$` before the first rewrite (before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: Oooh great! That works! But now all of the sudden the 7080 port starts to appear, after the redirect. I swear I didn't do anything else!

Comment: hmm I tried clearing the cache and all and really did not work. Would you mind trying yourself? interfusaoti.com.br/parceiros Thanks a lot for the help anyway, Croises, you've been a huge help!

Comment: Same problem with the 7080. It's not in the htaccess file here. You must have another configuration problem.

Comment: I managed to solve the 7080 port problem (probably it was being added due to configuration on the server indeed) by adding the following code: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(interfusaoti.com.br):7080$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: To anyone interested in SEO, I also added rel="canonical" to the page's head, since the `.php` address will be ranked together with the extensionless page.